SpringBoot SOAP configuration not called
I try to learn SpringBoot SOAP web-service implementation and don't understand why configuration methods not called. The configuration bean looks like this:
package hu.infokristaly.fileservice;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class SOAPWebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "FileUploadServiceWsdl")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition calculatorServiceDefinition(XsdSchema calculatorServiceSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdlDefinition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdlDefinition.setPortTypeName("FileUploadServicePort");
        wsdlDefinition.setLocationUri("/ws/fileuplaod-service");
        wsdlDefinition.setTargetNamespace("http://infokristaly.hu/fileuplaod");
        wsdlDefinition.setSchema(fileUplaodServiceSchema());
        return wsdlDefinition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema fileUplaodServiceSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("fileupload.xsd"));
    }

}

In other project the messageDispatcherServlet / fileUplaodServiceSchema / calculatorServiceDefinition methods called on startup.
Here is my Github repo
Please help me find solution. It's maybe just some misspell but I can't see the problem.
Thanks for all suggestions!

I moved the FileUploadEndpoint / SOAPWebServiceConfig / FileUploadImpl to the same directory as ForrasUploadSoapServerApplication and configuration loaded. How funny.

If your configuratoins are in different packages, use @ComponentScan on application like this:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hu.infokristaly"})
public class ForrasUploadSoapServerApplication {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ForrasUploadSoapServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

